# Функция fetch и if json файл

Tags: javascript, html, json, if, fetch

Помогите решить вопрос. Есть две функции - подключение web3 кошелька (connect), которая вызывает кошелек и подключает его к сайту, и функция оплаты (mint), которая так же вызывает кошелек для оплаты на сайте.

```
// connect function
async function connect() {
const doge = window?.DogeApi;
const { status } = await doge.enable();
if ( status === 'success') {
    const { userAddress } = await doge.userAddress();
    // const { network } = await doge.network();
  }
// or check isEnabled
  if (doge && (await doge.isEnabled())) {
    const { userAddress } = await doge.userAddress();
    // const { network } = await doge.network();
  }
  // mint function
  async function mint(){
const doge = window?.DogeApi;
if (await doge.isEnabled()) {
    const rs = await doge.useDoge(cost, toAddress, 'Buy Things Info');
    if (rs?.txid) {
      // successed
    }
```

Нужно как-то проверить список кошельков, которые находятся в файле spisok.json, чтобы воспользоваться функцией mint смогли только те кошельки, которые находятся в этом файле. Json находится на сервере, с этим проблем нет.  Я думаю, что это возможно через fetch и if, но не знаю как это сделать. Json выглядит так

```
[
  "DHN4hNPuPF6GxWo2RV6o7VgGFCi1g2zdfK",
  "DLQscvjJBMbePvYsYvHmWnx3gSdxw4qfUg",
  "DRN1UhVkrtmMfy6k17i84KdC9HHWxwkAVS",
  "D8t6BzGHcD5DSNT8LEcoq4cLe3zaX7gokZ"
]
```

Возможно у меня неверный формат json.
Пробую как-то так, но не могу сделать верный запрос:

```
 // mint function
      async function mint(){
    const doge = window?.DogeApi;
   const response = await fetch ('/spisok.json')
    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.responce === 200) {
        if (await doge.isEnabled()) {
            const res = await doge.useDoge(cost, toAddress, 'Buy Things Info');
             if (rs?.txid) {
          // successed
        }
      }
}}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: по поводу fetch('/spisok.json'), а сообственно какой ip либо доменное имя сервера? должно быть что то типо fetch('доменное имя или ip адресс сервера/spisok.json') или mint на сервере запускается?

Comment: все происходит на сайте (файлы с js и json в одной папке). конкретно с функцией mint проблем нет. она работает если не проверять адрес через json. но мне нужно сделать, чтобы воспользоваться функцией mint смогли только те кошельки, которые находятся в этом файле.

Comment: Не, я все еще не могу понять в чем проблема. await fetch(....) работает или нет? что в data или какая ошибка в devtools => network/console?

Comment: await fetch работает. данные приходят из json. но я не могу сравнить данные в json с кошельком, который подключился (doge.userAddress). по сути fetch работает, но ничего не делает, потому что я не знаю как задать, чтобы происходила проверка, есть этот адрес (userAddress) в json или нет. может я плохо формулирую, что мне надо...

Comment: не, с обяснением наверное все ок, это скорее связано с тем что я web3 не знаю. Я так и не смог понять проблему что бы попытатся помочь, сори.

Comment: тут как раз с web3 проблемы нет, всё работает. проблема состоит в том, что я не знаю как правильно написать запрос, чтобы проверять, есть подключенный кошелек (userAddress, который разный у всех пользователей) в моей файле json. 
`if (как тут правильно написать условие, что если кошелек userAddress есть в моем json, то можно дальше выполнять функцию)`

Comment: `// mint function
      async function mint(){
    const doge = window?.DogeApi;
   const response = await fetch ('/spisok.json')
    const data = await response.json();
    if (как тут правильно написать условие, что если кошелек userAddress есть в моем json, то можно дальше выполнять функцию) {
        if (await doge.isEnabled()) {
            const res = await doge.useDoge(cost, toAddress, 'Buy Things Info');
             if (rs?.txid) {
          // successed
        }
      }
}}`

Comment: data.includes(doge.userAddress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   const mint = async () => {
      try {
        const doge = window?.DogeApi;
        if (doge?.userAddress) {
          const response = await fetch('/spisok.json');
          if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            if (data.includes(doge.userAddress)) {
              // .........
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
```

если я правильно понял, то так.

Comment: спасибо, так работает. но теперь у меня появилась другая проблема уже с web3 кошельком: не считывается адрес кошелька, который подключается. если вписать текст, который есть в json, то всё работает.

Comment: @Valeriy Pbck выведи в консоль  ,doge, doge.userAddress мне интерестно что там.